# Decimal values are truncated in chrome when using ghostcript (gswin64c) to convert .ps files into pdf

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, ghostscript

We are using ghostscript (gswin64c) to convert .ps (post script) files into PDF files. Decimal values are printed correctly when opening the PDF in Internet explorer. But the values after decimal is getting truncated in Chrome. Please can anyone suggest how to fix this.

ex: In IE,  values prints as 15.12 on PDF. and on
    Chrome values prints as 15.1 on PDF. Number "2" is truncated.

Comment: You haven't supplied an example file, its not really going to be possible to say much without seeing it.

Comment: I can give the command for conversion we used :
PDF2PS.BAT_PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.20\\bin\\gswin64c.exe" -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4  -dFIXEDMEDIA -sPAPERSIZE="a4" -dCompressPages=true -dAutoRotatePages=/All -sDEVICE#pdfwrite

Comment: I'd then need the input file in order to make a PDF file which may or may not be the same as the one you produce. Not really a lot of help.  Frankly it sounds like a bug in Chrome, but there are legitimate reasons which **might** cause this sort of problem, however I'd need to see your PDF file to be able to tell. On a separate note; you are using an old version of Ghostscript. Current version is 9.52 and the version you are using has known security issues, especially with PostScript input.